# VBA sub-procedure(macro) to get sum and number of positive values in a range?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

could anyone please help me out with my VBA assignment? Writing a sub-procedure like this is bit too complicated for me. I need a sub-procedure, which finds positive values from a range of any size( the beginning cell is called "begin") and prints the sum and number of positive values to cells called "sum" and "number".

[image]

Comment: To better enable us to help, you need to show the code that you have written. If you haven't written any code yet, this question is premature.

Comment: Excel has a macro recorder. It's an excellent tool for learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub sum_positive()
Dim area
Dim total As Double
Dim quantity As Integer

'Select the range of the area you want to test
Range("begin").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

area = Selection

'Do a loop for each item you select to discover who is positive
For Each n In area
    If n > 0 Then
        total = total + n
        quantity = quantity + 1
    End If
Next n

'Return the values
Range("J1").Value = total

Range("L1").Value = quantity

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not really helping students to write their entire project for them.

Comment: Sorry about that, this is my first time answering a question, this site helps me a lot when I have doubt so I tried to help others, but in the future I will "control" myself.